# Design for API interaction

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I am currently designing a component of a system  (in c#) to interact with an api. The api calls are in the format:

```
http:// <name of api site>\< JSP page name>?<parameter set>
```

The call returns an xml document either containing the result of the call or an error message. I ultimately want the component to return an object of the following type:

```
 public readonly class APIResult<T>
 {
     public bool Success {get; set;}
     public T Details {get; set;}
 }
```

My current plan is to have a class that creates the URL,then passed it to another generic class (of type T) to call the API with the url, which interrogates the response, which returns a new APIResult with the details being poopluated from the Xml result deserialized.

I have 2 questions for the experts at SO.

1) Can anyone see a problem with this approach or suggest a better way of achieving my intentions.

2) Is there an elegant way of creating the URLs, rather than simply using a string.format with the parameters passed into the function.

Many thanks,

Ketchup

Comment: I'd make `APIResult` immutable.

Comment: +1 to what @CodesInChaos just said. Take a look at [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) which is part of the Asp.Net Web API.  If you're packing .Net 4.5, too, then you can use `await` to make retrieving data asynchronously very easy.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, i have made it readonly. And thank you for the await suggestion, i had planned on using the HttpClient, but was unaware of "await"

Comment: [Url Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx)  will help to build a url (or share common information between urls).

Answer (score 0):

Three recommendations:

1. Avoid using the Success property. That property will force you to check it every time you hit the API. You will end having code like this one everywhere:

   if(result.Success)
   {
      // do something
   }
   else
   {
      // and here... what!?
   }

   In OOP exceptions are preferable to error codes/flags.
2. Use attributes (decorations) to deserialize the API responses automatically (with no code for it).
3. Use UriBuilder to... well, build the uri: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.scheme.aspx